# how to pass props get persist using history.push

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history.js

i need to access data that are pass as a props from one component to another component by history.push,data becomes undefined when page reload,and i dont want to use redux so anyone have suggestion..Thankyou!

Comment: You can use react context here is the link https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Route state is ***very*** transient... it exists ***only during*** the route transition and long enough for the receiving component to access it. Any page reloads or navigating away will drop the route state. If will need to persist it ***somewhere*** after receiving it if you want to access it later after a page reload. You may want to just reconsider trying to render any specific page if it is missing route state, instead just redirecting back to a page the provides the state so any forward navigation can occur with the expected route state.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably passing a state object in the history.push call.

```
 history.push({
           pathname: '/path',
           state: { key1: 'hello this is data needed in another component',  }
       });
```

this behaves the same way as

```
history.push('/path')
```

But adds a state object which you can access in the other component on the location object.

In the component you redirect to you will do something like

```
const data = location.state?.key1
```

I am using the `?` there for cases where you use the component without being redirected, meaning the state would be null.

If you want your data to persist over reloads of the applications then consider using either the browsers localstorage, by setting an item in localstorage `localStorage.setItem("key", "value")` and then doing `localStorage.getItem("key") in the second component.
This becomes messy when you have multiple components calling this as there will be duplicate calls to the same state key. In which case redux would be a better option.

Another option would be to use query parameters and adding the state in the URL, which has the added bonus of being able to send someone a link to your app with a certain state already set.

Comment: but it will get undefined when we refresh the page and i need to persist that state data

Comment: In that case there is a few ways of going about it, I will update my original answer.